# Replace String values with value in Hash Map in Java

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have created a hash map that contains my Key Value pairs to utilize in replacing user input with the value corresponding to the respective key.
For exp i have multiple Strings like

```
 String pattern = "a+b";
 String pattern =  "C__a_plus_b+d"
 String pattern = "d+C__a_plus_b+F__c_plus_d"
```

and i have hashmap which contains there value like

```
HashMap<String, String> vals = new HashMap<>();

vals.put("a", "123");
vals.put("b", "13");
vals.put("C__a_plus_b", "123");
vals.put("d", "1623");
vals.put("C__a_plus_b", "5");
vals.put("F__c_plus_d", "15");
```

now i want to replace in string with there values from HashMap in my String and i want my output like

```
String pattern = "a+b"; 
                123+13

String pattern =  "C__a_plus_b+d"
                    123+1623
```

Comment: `C__a_plus_b` maps to both `123` and `5`. What is going on???

Comment: What have you written so far, code wise?

Comment: for(HashMap.Entry<String, String> val : lablemap.entrySet())
               {
                   result = operation.replace(val.getKey(), val.getValue());
                   operation = result;
               }

Comment: but it is not working, i think the special ch. are not replacing

Comment: + is a special character for a regex, escape that with "\\"

Comment: __ is not replacing with there value ,       + is replacing fine

Comment: You can create a method like this:  private static String getUpdatedString(String string) {
        String[] splittedArray = string.split("\\+");
        StringBuilder myResult = new StringBuilder();
        for (String mySubString : Arrays.asList(splittedArray)) {
            myResult.append(vals.get(mySubString)).append("+");
        }

        return myResult.toString().substring(0, myResult.toString().length() - 1);
    }

Comment: @proudandhonour i have used your method it is working fine if my string contains   String pattern = "a-b"; then can i used your method to split string with both (+ and -)

Comment: Yes, use can use that, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java 8 streams it should be something like:

```
String result = String.join(
    "+",
    Arrays.asList(pattern.split("\\+"))
        .stream()
        .map((String s) -> vals.get(s))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```